# Duplicate masters branches locally

Tags: git, gitbox

How can I merge these? I don't know how this has happened, I'v only worked with one branch before and today I was going to create a new one (the top blurred out one).

Please Note: I'm a front-end developer and basicly only know (about git) what I need to use this software (gitbox)

Edit: I cannot merge them in gitbox it seems, I can't select just one of them both are always selected, I've tried restarting gitbox as well.

[image: Duplicate master branches]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had two master branches, one called "master" and one called "master (computer_name)" because I stupidly tried to use Sugarsync (like dropbox) on my Sites folder, also I added the folder incorrectly so it duplicated almost every single file and added my computer name within parentheses.

(I had a bad cold when I did this)

I closed gitbox and deleted all duplicate FILES, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is nothing to merge. Probably just a bug on your GUI tool.
Try to open a terminal and list the branches of your project :

```
git branch
```

This command will display your actual branches and the one currently used with a star (*) in front.

Comment: Thanks! Although this was not the case, it lead me to find the real problem!